# Mysql Query Question

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with the following columns:

```
id (autoincremented primary key)
user_id
test_id
test_score
```

How can I get all test data tied to the users that have participated in test_id = 5.  I want all test data (not just test_id 5) for the users that have participated in that particular test.

Comment: You meant not just user_id 5 ? Your first and second statements seem contradictory to me. Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: @Mahesh If a user has taken test 5, return all of that user's test results for all tests. That's how I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'd want to do a self-join. Something like this would utilize indexes (assuming you have an index on `user_id` and an index on `test_id`, which you should):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM `tableName` t1
INNER JOIN `tableName` t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id
WHERE t2.test_id = 5
```

---

I guess that raises another point. How is your table indexed? Just the numeric primary key? You generally want to have indexes on all columns that are used in JOINs or WHERE clauses. Thus, you'd want to have an index on `user_id` and an index on `test_id`.

Can a user take the same test multiple times? If *not*, then you'd want restrict that by having a unique multiple-column ("composite") index across `user_id` and `test_id` together. And then add a regular index just to `test_id` for the WHERE clause.

Comment: Although this produced the same results as @AndrewR solution, yours was a slight bit faster to execute.  Thanks!

Comment: @VinnyD Glad to help. I think as your numbers of users and test results grow substantially, the difference in speed will become increasingly significant. With my basic tests (about 1000 records), this was one or two orders of magnitude faster than the other proposed solutions, thanks to the use of indexing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will get you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
  WHERE user_id IN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
    FROM table
      WHERE test_id = 5)
```

Comment: How is this different from - `select * from table where test_id = 5 ;`. Even simpler.

Comment: The nested select is not as efficient as the join operation because it executes the nested select once for every row in TABLENAME

Comment: @Mahesh - Your query doesn't return the results he requires.

Comment: @jkschneider I'm no MySql expert, but I think in this case, the subquery is only executed once. There aren't any dependencies between the two queries, and the WHERE in the subquery has a hard value. I haven't run this through an Explain, but I think this is just 2 simple queries.

Comment: @jkschneider I believe AndrewR is correct about it only being executed once since it is not row-dependent. My issue, rather, is that this (and currently the other answers) won't use indexes if available.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then the basic approach is to join the table on itself.

```
select allTestData.* from TEST_TABLE allTestData
left outer join (select user_id from TEST_TABLE where test_id = 5) testIdFive
on allTestData.user_id = testIdFive.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query,

```
SELECT test data 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE user_id IN (
  SELECT user_id 
  FROM TABLENAME 
  WHERE test_id = 5
)
```

Comment: The nested select is not as efficient as the join operation because it executes the nested select once for every row in TABLENAME

Comment: here you can get all testdata's tied to the users.